# Star ★ Not showing in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, html-entities

I have some html where the star is simply in the code like so:

```
<strong>This is my ★ star, I'm not using entities!</strong>
```

It works in Firefox, but not in Chrome (which displays a box). Why?

Comment: I'm on chrome and can see it just fine in this post...

Comment: ^this. Which localization of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Sorry, that was directed at Gil.

Comment: You should post a self-contained document that demonstrates the issue and/or a URL of such a document. The real problem is not in the code posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to expand on Gil's answer, the unicode character entity for star `&#9733;` was not showing for me in Chrome, but it was in Firefox. I found that just as Gil says, it *did* work in Chrome when it was in the html at page load, but it *did not* work in Chrome when the html containing the star was loaded subsequently via ajax.

Here's how I fixed it: this doesn't work...

```
<span>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</span>
```

... but this does - with the addition of the CSS `text-rendering` declaration...

```
<span style="text-rendering:auto;">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</span>
```

For the record I'm using Bootstrap on this site.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I'm using Bootstrap as well.

Answer (score 3):

It would be best if you used an HTML special character code to display it.

Give this a shot `&#9733;`

Comment: Yes. On a HTML page you'll get all kind of weird output if you don't stick to unicode characters http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML.

Comment: If this helps, then the real problem remains unfixed: the real problem would then be that the character encoding of the page has not been (properly) declared, and this forces browsers to guess, and they may differ then.

Comment: i did declare the character encoding.

Comment: Yes, if you are going to use extended characters like this, you should be explicit about your encoding-- usually utf-8. You can find character entities easily here: http://amp-what.com/#q=star

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this in the future, the problem looks like a Chrome bug when setting the HTML of a page element via JavaScript...

*update*: centralscru's answer solves the problem for me

Comment: This is the issue I have - I'm bringing in the content that contains the star via an ajax request after the page has loaded. Stars in the initial page show just fine. Now I just need to work out how to fix it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Typically any browser will display the square when it doesn't have that character defined in its char set.

So have you explictly provided a font, or are you relying on the browser's default? It may be that explictly changing font will give you the symbol, by virtue of it existing within the character set.

You might also want to consider using the HTML char code for it as well (`&#9733;`).

Answer (score 0):

Use a char code for that! I am using chrome and i can see that just fine!

Comment: I can see the star fine on stackoverflow.com with Chrome, and guess what? They don't use char code.

Comment: Same here, just saying, if he/she can't see it, try using a char code.