# PHP's htmlentities function doesn't encode ★ star

Tags: php, html-entities

```
htmlentities($this->name, null, "UTF-8");
```

Does not encode the star (★). How can I make it encode the star?

**Update:** `&acirc` doesn't render a star. Also, I'm using:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP >= 5.4, the default value of the `encoding` parameter was changed to `UTF-8`.

If you use:

```
htmlentities( "★", null, "ISO-8859-1");
```

The star character will be converted to `&acirc;`.

Comment: unfortunately &acirc; doesn't render the star.

Comment: note: the reason it didn't work had to do with a browser quirk (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941492/star-not-showing-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make it encode the star?

You can't. `htmlentities` does not encode all Unicode characters. But you can try some workarounds, like [this one](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#107985)

Or you can make use of output from `json_encode`:

```
$txt = preg_replace_callback(
    '/[\x80-\xFF]{3,}/', //do not trust this, it's only example that works for small range of unicode characters, that happens to include black star 
     function($m){ 
         return str_replace('\\u','&#x',trim(json_encode($m[0]),'"')).';';
      }, "Black ★ Star"
); // Black &#x2605; Star
```